# Positioning side and top bars with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, positioning

I am quite confused about positioning with TikZ. I am trying to create a template that has a top bar in gray as a header *only on the first page* and a left bar with a width equal to the left margin on all pages.

The problem is that tikz origin not only is not where I expect it to be, there are extra spaces I don't account for.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nofoot]{geometry}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}

%% Set background in all pages to the be a gray box in the left margin
\newcommand{\leftmarginbox}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=\paperheight] at (0cm,0cm) {};
    \node [circle, fill=blue] at (0, 0){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgContents{\leftmarginbox}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{6cm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{0pt}

\lhead{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=6cm] (box) at (0cm,0cm){};
    \node [circle, fill=red] at (0, 0){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
        \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,draft]{images/portrait.png}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
      {\Huge\color{mainblue} Foo}\\
      {\Large\color{black!80}---Bar---}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
    Tabular foo
    \vfill
  \end{minipage}
}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{%
  \begin{minipage}{7cm}
    RIGHTHEAD
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Problems:

- Top bar is not on the top edge and doesn't fill the whole paperwidth;
- margin par is not only 2.5cm and is not on the left edge;
- header should only be on the first page and should stretch to the width of the whole paper, instead it's constrained to textwidth;

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I cannot really understand what you mean by your second and third items. Perhaps that's not just me, your question has been here untouched for 3 hours. One thing which I could do, however, is to fix the overlay picture. You just put it at a random position and that's where it appears. You might want to work with absolute page coordinates.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nofoot]{geometry}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}

%% Set background in all pages to the be a gray box in the left margin
\newcommand{\leftmarginbox}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=\paperheight] at (0cm,0cm) {};
    \node [circle, fill=blue] at (0, 0){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgContents{\leftmarginbox}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{6cm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{0pt}

\lhead{%
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(X){\phantom{X}};}   
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node [anchor=north west,rectangle, fill=sidecolor, minimum
    width=\paperwidth, minimum height=6cm] (box) at (X.north-|current page.west){};
    \node [circle, fill=red] at ([xshift=\paperwidth/2]X.west){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
        \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,draft]{images/portrait.png}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
      {\Huge\color{mainblue} Foo}\\
      {\Large\color{black!80}---Bar---}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
    Tabular foo
    \vfill
  \end{minipage}
}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{%
  \begin{minipage}{7cm}
    RIGHTHEAD
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you explain the other items better, e.g. with a sketch, I will be happy to give it a try.